Do files get temporarily stored in the RAM when transferring data from one USB flash drive to another using a computer?
The title pretty much says it.
Or in other words, would someone be able to track the files or file names that were transferred from one USB flash drive to another (through the RAM of the computer)?

as other people have put in their answers, EVERYTHING happens in RAM.

Everything stored in memory is volatile memory.  While there are ways to some data from a memory module after it's been powered off.  It requires physical access to your machine. However, the likelihood of finding this data using this attack, is less than 0% since the memory the attack would find absolutely would not be filename of a file being transferred.  What specifically are you worried about? The title of your question does NOT clarify your actual question.

On a basic level for laymen: nothing happens without RAM so the answer is always "yes." You cannot bypass RAM.
Windows caches files as well, so the file contents will stay somewhere in RAM until that memory is needed for some other use. Cached files can be viewed with e.g. Microsoft Sysinternals RamMap
